# Add a line after every string match

Tags: perl, parsing

I have a sample file here http://pastebin.com/m5m40nGF

What I want to do is add a line after every instance of protein_id.
protein_id always has the same pattern:
TAB-TAB-TAB-protein_id-TAB-gnl|CorradiLab|M715_#SOME_NUMBER

What I need to do is to add this after every line of protein_id:
TAB-TAB-TAB-transcript_id-TAB-gnl|CorradiLab|M715_mRNA_#SOME_NUMBER

The catch is that #SOME_NUMBER has to stay the same.

In the first case, it would look like this:
94      1476    CDS
                        protein_id      gnl|CorradiLab|M715_ECU01_0190
                        transcript_id      gnl|CorradiLab|M715_mRNA_ECU01_0190
                        product serine hydroxymethyltransferase
                        label   serine hydroxymethyltransferase

Thanks! Adrian

I tried a perl solution, but I get an error.

```
open(IN, $in); while(<IN>){
   print $_;
   if ($_ ~= /gnl\|CorradiLab\|/) {
       $_ =~ s/tprotein_id/transcript_id/;
       print $_;
   }
    }
```

Error:

```
syntax error at test.pl line 3, near "$_ ~"
syntax error at test.pl line 7, near "}"
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Please indicate the language you are trying to parse the file with, and show us any code from your previous attempts at solving this problem. You've given too little information to work off of.

Comment: I was wondering if a combination of bash/sed/awk would work? Unfortunately, I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following perl script worked

```
my $in=shift;
open(IN, $in); while(<IN>){
    print $_;
    if ($_ =~ /gnl\|CorradiLab\|/) {
        my $tmp = $_;
        $tmp =~ s/protein_id/transcript_id/;
            print $tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Offering an update on existing answer because I feel it can be improved further:
Generally - the precise problem in the OP is this line:

```
 if ($_ ~= /gnl\|CorradiLab\|/) {
```

Because you've got `~=` not `=~`. That's what `syntax error at test.pl line 3, near "$_ ~"` is trying to tell you.

I would offer that improving on:

```
my $in=shift;
open(IN, $in); while(<IN>){
    print $_;
    if ($_ =~ /gnl\|CorradiLab\|/) {
        my $tmp = $_;
        $tmp =~ s/protein_id/transcript_id/;
            print $tmp;
    }
}
```

- `while ( my $tmp = <IN> ) {` skips the need to assign `$_`.
- 3 argument `open` with lexical filehandle is preferable. E.g. `open ( my $in, "<", "$input_filename" ) or die $!;` (You should test whether the `open` worked too)
- Explicit open may well be unnecessary if you're just reading a filename from command line. Using `<>` either reads filenames (opening and processing) or `STDIN`, which means your script becomes a bit more versatile.

Thus I would rewrite as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( my $line = <> ) {
    print $line;
    if ( $line =~ /gnl\|CorradiLab\|/ ) {
        $line =~ s/protein_id/transcript_id/;
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    print;
    if (m/gnl\|CorradiLab\|/) {
        s/protein_id/transcript_id/;
        print;
    }
}
```